# Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mongodb, model-view-controller

I want to upload an excel file for that I used ng-click and define the fileUpload($event) function in the app controller scope and with the help of xlsx I want to read the file in JSON but while running the code
getting this error-

```html
 <div>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
     <input type="button" value="Upload" ng-click ="fileUpload($event)">
 </div>
```

```js
   $scope.fileUpload = function(mE) {
        const file = mE.target.files[0];
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            var workBook = XLSX.read(fileReader.result, {type: 'binary'});
            var sheetNames = workBook.SheetNames;
            var ExcelData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workBook.Sheets[sheetNames[0]]);
                console.log(ExcelData);
         };
     };
```

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')
 at $scope.fileUpload 
 at site.js?ver=1:1:47308
 at t (site.js?ver=1:1:5384)
 at a.$eval (site.js?ver=1:1:4894)
 at a.$apply (site.js?ver=1:1:4119)
 at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (site.js?ver=1:1:5035)
 at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (site.js?ver=1:1:200)
 at p.handle (site.js?ver=1:1:40)
```

Comment: You are trying to get files from the value of button type input instead of the file type input above...

Comment: `$scope` I don't understand why this null? That's why this errors comming

Comment: Actually mR.target does not have anything called files on it ... That is the reason for the error ... target refers to the button type input, the files value is in the file type input above it ...

Comment: Created a fiddle as well here with the below solution implemented --> https://jsfiddle.net/b0n5xspo/

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your fileUpload function

```
const file  = document.getElementById('file-upload').files[0];
...
```

Comment: Have a look at this fiddle --> https://jsfiddle.net/b0n5xspo/